# U-SQL XML outputter using an XSD

Tags: xml, azure, xsd, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Is there a way to generate XML output using U-SQL that complies with an XSD ?

For example lets consider i have the following XSD.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="MyClass">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Field1"
                    type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="Field2"
                    type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I also have a table in ADLA called Person that has all the data i need for this schema.

I write the following query to get the data from ADLA

```
@res = SELECT * FROM person 
OUTPUT @res
TO "person.xml"
USING new XmlOutputter("abc")
```

I am aware i can use the XMLOutputter but i am unable to generate XML as output that will fit the schema. I can write a custom activity to do this but i want to make sure i am not missing something that can do this for me built in.

Any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: amit, could you please share with us how you solved this?

Comment: I ended up writing C# code to fetch the results from U-SQL and format them to XML using XSD tools. It was much easier to write and far easier to debug and maintain.

Comment: Which xsd tools did you use?

Comment: Why would you do that? Usql is made specifically for this purpose

Comment: I'm not criticizing at all. Just wanted to understand

Comment: I used the XSD generation tool from Microsoft to generate the Model and using C# code generated the appropriate XML